# Dynamic tabs in Angular : navigation in dynamic tab content

Tags: angular, typescript, web, tabs

I'm developing a demo app that contain a search bar, and with each search action a tab should be opened.

I succeeded to do that following this awesome article https://juristr.com/blog/2017/07/ng2-dynamic-tab-component/

The requirement is that each dynamic tab has his own context as the following images show [image]

[image]

Now inside the tab content I need to have navigation between different components.

I don't think that routing can be used, because as I mentioned, each tab has his own context.

what is the appropriate way to do so ? Any tutorials, any hint, or a place to start from would be very helpful ( I'm a beginner with angular )

Comment: I don't really understand the behaviour.. When you write in the search bar and you click the button "click me" it creates a new tab with the name you just wrote?
Then what exactly do you want to show into the tab?

Comment: thank you for replying
the code is like that because it still a demo, but here some more detail.
when you click the button it should open a tab with search result from the input, it well be a list in the tab content, let s say that it s component A that show the list, now after i click on an item of that list , another component B with the selected item detail should be shown in the same tab content. and so for each search... (each tab has his own context)
i hope this make it clear, and thx again

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If i understand correctly i think this could be one approach.

I tried to thik at something simple...

In you tab content you write the html code like this:

```
<div class="listContent" *ngIf="showDetail==false">
<!-- Populate this list as you are doing -->
<ul>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>Of</li>
    <li>Items</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="detailContent" *ngIf="showDetail==true">
  <!-- Put here the detail to show after the item click -->
</div>
```

In your typescript file you can keep the state of the content to show through a boolean variable, in this case i used `showDetail`.
Then at the click of an item of the list you switch this variable, so the content will be shown.

You component should have a function like this:

```
  showDetail: boolean = false;
  
  switchContent(){
     //Set here all the variables
     // and the content you want to show

     showDetail = true
  }
```

Don't forget to have a **"go back" button** or something like that, so you can set `showDetail = false` and return to the previous list

### More complex way

If you are not already using `<router-outlet>` you can place it inside the tab content. Then you create two components (one for displaying the list anc one for the detail) and then you navigate through them using routing.
For details on routing see: https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route